# Select_Tag not working in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

Here is my code for `select_tag`

```
<%= select_tag :tp, options_for_select([["movable",1],["fixed",2]]), :prompt => "select type of asset" %>
```

it works if i replace by:

```
<%= f.text_area :tp %>
```

If this in not enough i will give more code as you desire:
here is the log after i use `select_tag`

```
Started POST "/assets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-07 23:40:34 +0530
Processing by AssetsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Gib6rSODjXgXLZ9+5sDcq0ZatkA7144hU+Em2X7KONU=", "asset"=>{"name"=>"", "location"=>"", "cost"=>""}, "tp"=>"1","commit"=>"Save"}
(1.0ms)  BEGIN
(1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000new
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
[2014-03-07 23:40:34] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: localhost:3000new (or bad hostname?)
    F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:1203:in `rescue in merge'
     F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:1200:in `merge'
     F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpresponse.rb:275:in `setup_header'
    F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpresponse.rb:205:in `send_response'
    F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in'run'
    F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-07 23:40:36 +0530
```

**Error after changing to `real_assets_path**

```
Started GET "/real_assets/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-09 13:56:47 +0530
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigrationLoad(1.0ms)SELECT"schema_migrations".* FROM"schema_migrations"
Processing by AssetsController#new as HTML
Rendered assets/new.html.erb within layouts/application (30.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 98ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `assets_path' for #<# <Class:0x545bb78>:0x545aeb8>):
1: <div class = "container">
2: <div id = "assetnew">
3:  <%= form_for(@asset) do |f| %>
4:  <center><h1>Add Asset</h1></center>
5:   <div class = "well">
6:     <a class ="red">
  app/views/assets/new.html.erb:3:in`_app_views_assets_new_html_erb___457532114_11608392'


Rendered     

F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
 Rendered  

F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered  

F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (18.0ms)
```

Comment: have you tried `f.select`?

Comment: yeah it show ``undefined method `select_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x3e144d0>`` error

Comment: You shouldn't be using `assets` as a resource, you're going to have all kinds of conflicts with the asset pipeline.

Comment: yeah i have already gone through many problems, but this prob isnt that, i will change later just want to solve this select problem

Comment: What do you mean by the `select_tag` doesn't work? Is it throwing error? or just not showing up?

Comment: Are you getting `undefined method 'select_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x3e144d0>` error when you use `select_tag`?

Answer (score 1):

**Assets**

This is the error Rails is returning:

```
ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: localhost:3000new (or bad hostname?)
```

Without seeing your form, it seems you've got an issue with calling your resource `/assets` (as mentioned in the comments)

Basically, Rails treats the assets pipeline as a `base` directory - `localhost:3000/your_asset_file.png` -- it looks like this is what's happening here

Because your app is referencing `/assets`, I would surmise it's confusing it with the assets dir. Try doing this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :assets, as: "real_assets", path: "real_assets" #-> real_assets_path - /real_assets
```

---

**Select**

The select problem is likely caused by your `assets` path problem

[`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) is a standalone helper method (doesn't need any FormBuilder to help it). This means you should be able to just use it in an `.html.erb` file without any problems

The syntax for the select looks okay, so I'd recommend if you get your assets path fixed, you should be able to use it

Comment: `undefined method `assets_path' for #<#<Class:0x8349990>:0x8348f70>`..This is what i get after adding as per your answer

Comment: Change to real_assets_path

Comment: i have edited my question you can see my error..also changes to real_assets_path